# Componente Autocomplete VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Quero criar um componente de `autocomplete`, então tenho o seguinte codigo.

```
<Input v-model="form.autocomplete.input" @on-keyup="autocomplete" />
<ul>
    <li @click="selected(item, $event)" v-for="item in form.autocomplete.res">
        {{item.title}}
    </li>
</ul>

autocomplete(e){
    const event = e.path[2].childNodes[4]

    if(this.form.autocomplete.input.length > 2){
        this.Base.get('http://localhost:3080/post/search/post', {
            params: {
                q: this.form.autocomplete.input
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.form.autocomplete.res = res.data

            if(this.form.autocomplete.res.length > 0)
                event.style.display = 'block'
        })
    }
},
selected(item, e){
    this.form.autocomplete.item = item
    console.log(e)
}
```

Porem, como eu faria para ter o retorno apos selecionar meu item no arquivo principal?

Ex:

```
Home.vue

<Autocomplete :url="www.url.com/test" />
```

Ao selecionar o item que eu quero do meu `autocomplete`, como pegar o retorno dele e armazena-lo nesse arquivo, como se eu estivesse usando `v-model`?

OBS: A URL e outras informações irei passar via `props` posteriormente.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor essa parte "como pegar o retorno dele e armazena-lo nesse arquivo, como se eu estivesse usando v-model" ?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte No exemplo a cima do meu componente, eu armazeno o retorno ao selecionar o item da lista em `form.autocomplete.item`, porem esse valor fica armazenado em `autocomplete.vue` e não no arquivo que estou utilizando que no caso seria o `Home.vue` (ou qualquer outro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que a lógica dos componentes leva a um padrão onde o `v-model` vai atrelado a definição do componente filho para que o mesmo possa captura-lo, trata-lo e até emitir novamente para o pai, isso pode ser feito através do `@input`, exemplo...

```js
Vue.component('products-list', {
  template: '#my-input',
  data: function() {
    return{
        product : {
         name: ""
        }
      }
    },
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    product: {
      name: "",
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <products-list v-model="product.name"></products-list>
  <br>Componente pai : {{product.name}}
</div>

<template id="my-input">
  <div>
    <input @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)"
    v-model="product.name"
    />
    <br><br>Componente filho : {{product.name}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu